# Robolectric-Gradle plugin running single test

Tags: android, testing, gradle, robolectric, robolectric-gradle-plugin

Is it possible to run single tests using Robolectric-Gradle plugin?

I tried with this:

```
./gradlew test -Dtest.single=testName
```

But it is not working.

Comment: It seems that it can be done with `includePatterns` with some hacking but not directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Made the same mistake myself. Thats the format for jcandksolutions plug-in (at least that's what I was using). `-Dtest.single=<test name>` is not supported by RoboE-Gradle plugin.

Use `--tests <test class name>` mechanism.  This can be either `--tests <classpath of test>` or wildcard with `--tests *.*Test`

Comment: Whenever I try running this I'm getting `Unknown command-line option '--tests'`, is there something I'm missing here?

I'm using the RoboE-Gradle plugin (v 0.14.1) and running the command `./gradlew clean test --tests MyTest`

Comment: First of all, `-Dtest.single=<test name>` is the generic syntax to make Gradle define a JVM system property called `test.single`, i.e. `-D` is handled by Gradle itself, not by any plugin. Similarly, `--tests` is a command line option [provided by the Java plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#test_filtering), it's not an option to a task (Gradle tasks cannot take command line arguments). That said, the question is whether the Robolectric plugin supports the `-Dtest.single` or `--tests` snytax, and in my experience it does support both.

Answer (score 1):

The method described in the original question does work but you must be working with the latest versions of the robolectric gradle plugin as per [docs here](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin)

So currently in your dependencies section you'll need

```
classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:1.0.1'
```

If you are updating from 0.xx, as I was, you'll probably need to change the dependencies from `androidTestCompile` to `testCompile` to build your tests.

Then as above

```
./gradlew test -DtestDebug.single=<NameOfTestClass>
```

Will run just your single test (Notice it assumes your test class ends in *Test so you can skip it from the command)

Comment: And if you are running into trouble getting android studio to pick up your test classes after changing `androidTestCompile` to `testCompile` then this line will fix that up for you `androidTestCompile configurations.testCompile.dependencies`